# Can response data from core reporting api be grouped?

Tags: google-analytics-api

**Explanation:**
I am able to query the Google Core reporting APIv3 using the client library to get data on pageviews for specific URLs of a website I am working on. I want to get data(pageviews) for each day within a specified range. So far I am simply looping through the range, sending individual request to the API. in each request I am setting the same value for the start date and the end date.

**Problem:**
Obviously this gets the job done, BUT it is certainly not the best way to go about it. Because, assumming I want to get data for the past 3 months for each of about 2000 URIs. Then I will need 360000 number of requests and that value is well over the limit quota defined by Google.

**Potential solution:** So one way I thought of solving this issue is probably to send a request setting start-date and end-date to be a week apart but the API will return a sum of the values rather than the individual values.

**main question:** So is there a way to insist that these values should not be added up and returned as a sum but rather returned (as associative array or something like that) separately for each.

I hope the question is clear and that there is a solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very straightforward:

Metric: **ga:pageview**, Dimension: **ga:date**, Set a filter for your pagepath, and set a **start-date** and **end-date**.

Example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3Axxyyzz&dimensions=ga%3Adate&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&filters=ga%3Apagepath%3D%3D%2Ffaq.html&start-date=2013-06-27&end-date=2013-07-11&max-results=50
```

This will return the pageviews for that the **faq.html&** page for each day in the time-frame.

You should check out the [QueryExplorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/).  Great tool to find out how to structure queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just what I was looking for! I guess I should be playing the query explorer a little bit more! Thanks!

Comment: Yes query explorer is the real start point.After making and verifying the query via query explorer one should replicate the result via api